# How to fix PermissionError:[Errno 13] Permission denied, when opening a csv file?

Tags: python

When I Code this in python I get an error, but I don't no why, it is an csv file 
:

```
import csv    
with open(r'C:\Users\janzi\Documents') as csvdatei:
    csv_reader_object = csv.reader(csvdatei, delimiter=',')
        print(csv_reader_object)
```

#### the error/exception I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/janzi/Desktop/Instagram bot.py", line 3, in <module>
    with open(r'C:\Users\janzi\Documents') as csvdatei:
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\janzi\\Documents'
```

Comment: 'C:\Users\janzi\Documents' this is not a valid path. provide full path including the csv file. for example: `with open(r'C:\Users\janzi\Documents\foo.csv') as fp:`

Comment: Thank you now it works

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to open your Documents **directory**, not your csv **file**.

Specify the entire path to the file, including the filename.

Answer (score 0):

'C:\Users\janzi\Documents' is not a full path, you need to specify the file name and type: 'C:\Users\janzi\Documents\myfile.csv'

Comment: this is not an answer and shouldnt be. this is a comment!

Comment: @Adam this is a perfectly acceptable answer, as it describes the cause of the OP's problem and provides a solution. Questions should not be answered in comments.